# SwiftUI list Move and select rows

Tags: swiftui-list

I'm trying to implement two actions on list rows as the following photo

[image]

The first one is to make it move and rearrange it and done by using "ForEach" with ".onMove" so that is done, the second is make multi-selection rows by using "List" with "selection" option so that done too.
The problem is I can't combine those two options, because one of them use "List" and the other use "ForEach" and when I do that an unexpected behavior is happing.
So did anyone can help me with this problem, please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a possible solution how to combine Selection and onMove.

```
struct ContentView : View {
        
    @State var items = ["Dave", "Tom", "Jeremy", "Luke", "Phil"]
    
    @State var selectedItems : Set<String> = Set<String>()
    
    var body : some View {
        NavigationView {
            List(selection: $selectedItems) {
                ForEach(items, id:\.self) { item in
                    Text(item).tag(item)
                }.onMove(perform: move)
            }
            .navigationBarItems(trailing: EditButton())
        }
    }
    
    func move(from source: IndexSet, to destination: Int) {
        items.move(fromOffsets: source, toOffset: destination)
    }
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what the poster is trying to avoid. When you have multiple items selected and you move one of them, all of them will move.

Answer (score 0):

In my app, davidev's answer sort-of works.  It allows multiple rows to be selected, and the handles appear when the move is initiated.  However, it did not allow placing the selection to a new location (ie, did not move). still working on why it won't actually move.

Comment: This answer is more of an comment to the accepted answer.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30708541)

Answer (score 0):

Just don't use selection

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var orderArray:[String] = ["A", "B","C"]
    @State private var selectedSet:Set<String> = Set<String>()
    var body: some View {
        List{
            
            ForEach(orderArray,id:\.self){ name in
                HStack{
                    
                    Image(systemName:  selectedSet.contains(name) ? "checkmark.circle.fill" : "circle")
                        .foregroundColor(Color.accentColor)
                        .font(.system(size:20,weight: .semibold))
                    Text( name )

                    Spacer()
                }
                    .contentShape(Rectangle())
                    .onTapGesture {
                        if selectedSet.contains(name){
                            selectedSet.remove(name)
                        }else{
                            selectedSet.insert(name)
                        }
                    }
            }
            .onMove(perform: move)
        }
        .environment(\.editMode, .constant(EditMode.active) )
    }
    
    func move(from source: IndexSet, to destination: Int) {
        
        orderArray.move(fromOffsets: source, toOffset: destination)
        
        }
}
```